# Get HTML attributes from loop

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I have a list of items:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="//external-link.com">
        <img src="main-image.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Description lorem here </p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="//external-link.com">
        <img src="main-image.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Description lorem here </p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="//external-link.com">
        <img src="main-image.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Description lorem here </p>
</div>
```

I want to extract the text of the `<h2>` tag, and the "src" and "href" of the `<a>` and `<img>` tags, but I can't figure out how to extract the "src" and "href" attributes.

This is something like what I'm using:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

pageURL = 'http://ticketdriver.com/amg/buy/tickets'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(pageURL), nil, 'UTF-8')

page.css('.item').each do |node|
    title = node.css('h2').text
    srcUrl = node.css('img')['src']
end
```

The `text` part is working but I can't access the key and value for child elements of ".item". I tried `children[0]`, `[0]['src']` , `[:src]`, `attr()`, `attribute()` and a few more.

I'm completely out of ideas and Google search pages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid using salutations ("Hi i'm new to Ruby and nokogiri."), valedictions or signatures. Stack Overflow isn't a conversation, instead we're writing articles on how to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html><body>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="//external-link.com">
            <img src="main-image1.jpg" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <h2> Title1 </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="//external-link.com">
            <img src="main-image2.jpg" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <h2> Title2 </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="//external-link.com">
            <img src="main-image3.jpg" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <h2> Title3 </h2>
    </div>
</body></html>
EOT

items = doc.search('.item').map { |item|
  {
    title: item.at('h2').text,
    src: item.at('img')['src']
  }
}
```

Which results in:

```
items
# => [{:title=>" Title1 ", :src=>"main-image1.jpg"},
#     {:title=>" Title2 ", :src=>"main-image2.jpg"},
#     {:title=>" Title3 ", :src=>"main-image3.jpg"}]
```

I'm deliberately only getting the "src" attribute from the `<img>` tag. Given the code above you can figure out how to get what you want from the `<a>` tags.

Notice that I'm using the generic [`search`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Asearch) rather than [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Acss). Nokogiri is smart enough to differentiate between CSS and XPath selectors most of the time. The only time I use either [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Acss) or [`xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Axpath) is when Nokogiri can't figure it out. I use CSS because it's generally simpler and more easily read.

Also, notice that I don't use `node.css('h2').text`. [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Acss) returns a NodeSet, which is akin to an Array, whereas [`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Aat) returns a single Node. In your code you're masking the difference between the two, but using `css`, `xpath` or the generic [`search`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Asearch) is a bug in waiting. Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html><body>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>baz</p>
</body></html>
EOT

doc.search('p').text # => "foobarbaz"
doc.at('p').text # => "foo"
```

What this means is, if [`search`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Asearch) or one of its specific methods returns a NodeSet, `text` will return the text of all Nodes in that set, which is rarely what you want. Instead, you need to use `at` to find the specific child-node you want and then extract its text. How you do that is a different question, but it's easily done.